# Grid Layout and CardView Not Showing up on old Android Device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview, cardview

I am looking for a solution. 
Grid Layout using cardView is showing up on latest device nicely, but the older devices like Lollipop and some other versions of Android device not showing up the the Grid Layout and CardView. 
please give me the solution as if i can buildup my project.
Thanks

here is my layout code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.facebook.ads.AudienceNetworkActivity"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="230dp"
        android:id="@+id/bg_top_header"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_bg_topheader"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/user_photo"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="বাংলা ইসলামিক "
        android:id="@+id/user_name"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="নিউজ পোর্টাল"
        android:id="@+id/user_id"
        android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/user_photo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/user_name"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp" />

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
        android:padding="14dp"
        android:rowCount="3"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/bg_top_header"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_our_islam"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/cardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/ourislams" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/t_ourislam"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_islam_times"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/cardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/islamtimes" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/t_islamtimes"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_insaf"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/cardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/insaf"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/t_insaf"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_patheo"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/cardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/patheo"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/t_patheo"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_iab_news"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/cardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/iabnews"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/t_iab"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/btn_suggest"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:background="@color/cardColor"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="6dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@drawable/suggest"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="উপদেশ দিন"
                    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/textcardColor"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/mo_re"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>








    </GridLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tanbhirhossain.binp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 10
        versionName "10.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: When you use constraint layout, avoid hardcoding the dimensions as much as possible. You have completely neglected the power of Constraint Layout by hardcoding each and every dimensions.

Comment: can you show your build.gradle app module

Comment: please check build.gradle file added

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Constraint Layout don't make them hard code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and use scroll view inside Constraint Layout to handle view for lower end device as screen size are too small.

Answer (score 0):

not supporting in Lollipop versions after androidx, android studio does not support v7 libr